# Describe for PathAssistant in Apex?

Tags: apex, pathassistant

So salesforce has this awesome Path component, which I have created to display the stages of the opportunity.

I was trying to check if there is is a way to get the path metadata in apex. Like for which step, what fields are used.

I got the reference of this [Metadata Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_pathassistant.htm?search_text=path) which can be used.

But, I am not sure, if there is anything like `Describe` for `sObjects` which can directly give the details of the PathAssistant with all the attributes.

Need some guidance on this.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to get that information using describe calls. You have to use the Metadata API to get these details.

I had the same problem in past and after spending a lot of time I just came to a conclusion that it doesn't support the describeSObjects calls.

To prove this theory, I can only give you the following link -
[Tooling API Link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_pathassistant.htm)

if you check the above link you will find that Supported SOAP Calls doesn't list the describeSObjects call. For other objects, you can see it. I know it's my assumption but I had to use the metadata API for the solution.

Comment: Can you add a link to any documentation to verify this claim?

Comment: @battery.cord - I hope you may find the revised answer useful.  Thanks